# Is it possible to make a numerically-prefixed hotkey run a function that many times?

Tags: vimscript, normal-mode, repeated-commands

I find that if you enter a numeric prefix prior to executing an ex command, the convention that it applies is to set up the command to prep an operation across a line range. It is explained in the documentation,

> A NUMBER OF LINES
>
> When you know how many lines you want to change, you can type the
>   number and then ":".  For example, when you type "5:", you will get:
>
> ```
>     :.,.+4
> ```
>
> Now you can type the command you want to use.  It will use the range
>   "." (current line) until ".+4" (four lines down).  Thus it spans five
>   lines.

Now what I am dealing with is a custom function of mine, this one:

```
function! MyAmazingEnhancedDot()
    if v:hlsearch == 1
        :normal! .n
    else
        :normal! .j
    endif
endfun
```

This is just a way to streamline repetitive tasks that include repeating an operation on a range of lines or over a series of search matches.

This function is bound to a hotkey. Such as <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> or whatever.

My aim is to be able to do something very powerful: I should be able to type `/varName<CR>ciwnew-var<ESC>n9<Alt+.>` to achieve renaming 10 instances of `varName` to `new-var`.

What actually happens if I do this is that it does not perform the renaming and the 9 lines are manipulated with my `.`-saved edit operation from column 0.

I can only assume that Vim is interpreting my keystrokes thus: `:.,.+8 normal! .n`.

On the glass-half-full side, the `:normal! .j` case of the bind actually works, because the `j` motion having no effect is of no consequence in this situation. (I still need the `j` to make it work in a non-numeric-prefixed interactive use case).

So my question is how can I override the line-expansion behavior that Vim applies to my bind? What would be fantastic is if I can read in the numeric prefix as an argument or something like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default vim treats all functions as if they are default ex commands, i.e. any prefixed numbers are used as `{range}`. To change this you need to modify your function and your map to use a count.

**Map with count**

Maps can take a count and are made available via `v:count` and `v:count1`. The first contains 0 if no count is provided and the later contains 1 as the default. You can create a map to your function:

```
nnoremap <M-.> :<C-u>call MyAmazingEnhancedDot(v:count1)<cr>
```

For more info `:h v:count`

**Commands with count**

Commands can have the option of either a `{range}` or a `count` as a prefix. When creating the command the flag `-count` disables the range option and defaults the `<count>` variable to 0. Optionally a default value can be provided `-count=N`. The prefix value is then available via the variable `count` in your function.

A command using count would look like this:

```
:command -count=1 EDot call MyAmazingEnhancedDot(<count>)
```

Now when you call `9EDot` your function is called with the count of `9` instead of a range.

For more info see `:h command-count`

**Both examples**

Here is your code:

```
function MyAmazingEnhancedDot(count)
  let c = a:count
  while c > 0
    if v:hlsearch == 1
      :normal! .n
    else
      :normal! .j
    endif
    let c -= 1
  endwhile
endfunction

command -count=1 EDot call MyAmazingEnhancedDot(<count>)

nnoremap <M-.> :<C-u>exe v:count1 . "EDot"<CR>
```

Now you can do your example

```
/varName<CR>ciwvar-name<esc>n9<M-.>
```

Comment: Cool. Now there seems to be too **many** ways to solve my problem! I understand that you combined both mechanisms in the example you gave in order to illustrate how to use them. But I wonder if it isn't sufficient to just use `nnoremap <M-.> :<C-u>call MyAmazingEnhancedDot(v:count1)<cr>` and skip the `command -count=1 EDot call MyAmazingEnhancedDot(<count>)`?

Comment: Skipping the command option is fine. The only benefit you get from the command option is being able to call it from ex commands such as `:9EDot`. If you don't use ex commands a lot then skip it.

Comment: Awesome. Now your perfect answer is complete!