# How can I prevent (or at least prompt to confirm) absurdly large numbers from being used to prefix commands?

Tags: normal-mode, repeated-commands

It doesn't happen as often as you'd think, but it happens occasionally, and I don't even own a cat.

Basically if you mash the number row or numpad and then happen to hit a keycombo that triggers a repeatable command, it is possible to inadvertently command Vim to perform a task several thousand, million, or even billion times. This easily gets out of control and may result in data loss.

So I wonder if there is a configuration or something in the source code we can change to serve as a sanity check to prevent this sort of DoS.

Comment: Just to be sure that I understand your question: you regularly type by mistake some sequence like `144477@@` or `99999.` and you want to stop those executions when the number is too big? Am I right? (I have to ask because that seems a little bit weird to me, I never had this problem)

Comment: Why not… pay attention on what you do?

Comment: Use persistent undo and increase `undolevels`.  It's a great safety net, and a pretty useful feature by itself.

Comment: @statox yes, that's right. romainl has a valid point too, but it seems irrelevant to the question. The question remains, and it may not be as "serious" as other questions, but a question it is nonetheless. I simply think that it makes sense to be able to specify an upper bound on this to prevent accidental denial-of-service. As for the suggestion about undolevels, yes that can be relevant if this overflows undo buffer as well, I hadn't considered it either. (A not so contrived example -- I have a 60% keyboard, the top border row is numbers. I pick it up with my hand. Forget to unplug it. etc.)

Comment: @Steven I understand that was a real question, I wasn't  criticizing it I just wanted to be sure I understand. Of course as long at it is on topic and useful for other people your questions is worth being asked and answered. Unfortunately I don't have a good answer and I also think romainl has a good point but I hope you're satisfied with the answer you found or someone will provide you what you're expecting :)

Comment: You can use `set showcmd` to show the keys you've typed in the bottom-right corner.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I think that would qualify as a "prompt to confirm" since it shows on the screen.  I recommend adding it as an answer (probably along with how to add it as a default option in `.vimrc`, so the answer is fully self-contained.)

Answer (score 2):

I find that you are usually able to interrupt the repetition process by sending a SIGINT (<kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>). As long as some vimscript is not running a really long inner loop, there is no DoS concern.

See [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3182/is-it-possible-to-make-a-numerically-prefixed-hotkey-run-a-function-that-many-ti) for an example of a plugin may contain a function that loops depending on the entered number.

For almost all intents and purposes this issue here is a hypothetical one.

Comment: "this issue is a hypothetical one"... No, it isn't. I've had to work on SSH on my phone over 2G connections, where I have accidentally missed a keystroke or made multiple keystrokes while typing in anticipation, resulting in very similar situations (maybe not 99999, but smaller numbers yes).

Comment: Cool, yeah a slow terminal emulator (depending on the amount of changing that vim is applying) can exacerbate problems by adding processing delay on the client side. Gotta get to Ctrl+C quickly!

Comment: You can just use `<Esc>`, you don't need to use `<C-c>`. The difference is that `<C-c>` aborts whatever Vim is doing (such as running a function), and `<Esc>` doesn't. You almost never want to use `<C-c>` unless you want to "kill" something.